# JQuery UI Clip effects is not working for positioning absolute

Tags: jquery-ui, css-position

I have an image which absolutely positioned and I would like to apply jquery clip effect on it. But I am having trouble to achiever the expected behavior.

Below I have pasted the code which I am trying.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.10/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
        // run the currently selected effect
        function runEffect() {
            // get effect type from 
            var selectedEffect = "clip";

            // most effect types need no options passed by default
            var options = { direction : "vertical" };

            // run the effect
            $( "#effect" ).hide( selectedEffect, options, 500);
                    };      

        // set effect from select menu value
        $( "#t" ).click(function() {
            runEffect();
            return false;
        });

            });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="images">
    <img id="effect" src="Google_Maps_Icon.png" style="position:absolute; top:200px; left:200px;"/>
    <a id="t" href="#">click</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Expected Behavior is as mentioned on jquery UI website:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/

Any thoughts how can I achieve this ?

Thanks
Sahil

Comment: What effect do you get? It works fine for me, copying the exact code, with a different image.

Comment: Image slides upwards and disaapears instead of actually staying at that position and perform effect.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of testing, I found it is the "top" property that is playing up. A workaround is to surround the `<img>` by another element, e.g. `<div>`, and delegate the positioning to that parent element:

```
<div style="position:absolute; top:200px; left:200px;">
    <img id="effect" src="http://w.ws.static.wireshark.net/image/wsbadge64.png" />
</div>
```